# how to manually trigger the search event in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

// unbind the search event of all select2 upon open
// this is to remove all the default event of select2 search field and use my custom instead

```
$(document).on('select2:open','.select2', function (e) {
   $('input.select2-search__field').off();
});
```

// manually search select2

```
$('body').on('keyup', 'input.select2-search__field', function(event) {
    var value = $('.select2-search__field')[0].value;
    var resultsId = $(this).parents('span').next().find('ul').attr('id');
    if (value != "") {
        // trigger search after the 'enter' key has been pressed
        if (event.which == 13) {
            if(resultsId.match(/SomeId/)){
                // other select2 with custom ajax search
            } else if (resultsId.match(/SpecificSelect2/)) {
                // this won't work since the event is already unbind
                $(this).trigger('input');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I look up the programmatic control method of select2 but it seems there is no way to bind the event again.

Is there a way to trigger the function for the default search event manually?

Comment: So you want to show/hide the search box ?

Comment: No. By default, the search box of select2 triggers its event upon input. Instead of upon input of the user, I would like it to trigger the search event upon pressing enter key. My first code removes all the event in the element so that it won't invoke the search by keypress.